# How to avoid top space and make full dimension in justgage?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, raphael, graphael, justgage

Is there any option to avoid top space. 
Actually I am looking solution to show as full width and full height.

[image]

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/ugFmE/12/

```
var g = new JustGage({
  id: "spedometer",
  title: "Monthly expense",
  value: 1986, 
  min: 0,
  max: 2450,
  shadowOpacity: 0,
  relativeGaugeSize: true
});
```

Comment: There is likely some css you could fiddle with to fix that.

Comment: @JustinC css solution effecting responsive :( please have a look fiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/ugFmE/11/

Answer (score 5):

Add some css to the div to make it go up...

```
#spedometer{ 
    margin-top: -##px 
}
```

*where '##' is the amount of pixels you would like to move the div towards the top..*

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/ugFmE/17/

Comment: By now this is the only way to go. Given the fact that the creator said, eleven months ago, that the option to hide the title was on the works... and still nothing. This is not the best solution for responsiveness sake, but does the trick..

here: https://github.com/toorshia/justgage/issues/60

Comment: You can make it work responsively by using % instead of px:
#speedometer {
    margin-top: -20%;
}

Answer (score 1):

Use style attribute of div tag and change value of top-margin to negative. I hope that would help you

```
<div id="g1" style= margin-top:-100px;></div>

window.onload = function () {
    var g1 = new JustGage({
        id: "g1",
        value: getRandomInt(0, 100),
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        relativeGaugeSize: true
    });
}
```